# iphone, how to implement 'upgrde app ' with outh through AppStore?

Tags: iphone

I want 'upgrade feature' in my iPhone app, how to say, if user tap a 'upgrade' button, then the app will access online upgrade version server and download newest modules file, after that, the app can use the newest modules...

I am not sure that whether cocoa can like C++ to call 'Load DLL', but I assume that should have some way can do the similar feature...

any one can give tips ?

Thanks a lots for your time .

Regards

Comment: Is that even allowed? I'm not sure, but I don't believe so, because that way you could push an app to the appstore, then upgrade this app to something that wouldn't get apples approval, because you're bypassing apple's app review process.

Comment: If the user has to pay for it, it'll most probably be rejected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App store apps cannot modify their object code (compiled ARM code).  An app's code is signed by Apple, and the app bundle is not user writable.  If you want to add an object code feature, it has to be built into the app as submitted to Apple for review, even if possibly only enabled after inApp purchase.

You **can** modify an app by downloading new HTML/CSS/Javascript and executing it in a UIWebview, so if you can add your upgraded functionality with HTML5 content, it might be acceptable.  You can also download and modify UI data, such as button titles, text labels, view positions, images, audio, etc.  Apple has a WWDC 2010 video on this methodology.  I think it was called Data Driven app design, or some such.

But no DLL's or other executable code modules of any other kind are allowed, according to the SDK agreement.